# SQL SELECT AND UPDATE FUNCTION

Tags: php, html, sql, phpmyadmin, sql-update

I want to execute this code but I need one more variable that I dont know how to find.

I have this:

```
SELECT CODE = 'P1R2G1' and CATEGORY = '20M' 
IF RANK op1 = '1' 
THEN UPDATE tourneyeventgamesPuertoRicoVolleyballChampionship
SET ref = 'OP1 VALUE' 
WHERE ref = '1P3R2G1' and 
CATEGORY = '20M';
```

how can I change op1 value for what is actually in that field?

Lets say that I have USA in op1. I want USA to substitue 1p3r2g1

Comment: I'm not clear on exactly what you are trying to do.  Other than in the 'if', you aren't using any of the variables you are setting...

Comment: I don't understand the question either, nor the code, but I suggest `SET ref = op1`... I've known it to work in some cases...

Answer (score 0):

You have to use CASE statements if you want to show some other value based on the value that is found inside a column for a record.